# Where's the inverse of Math.tanh in the math libraries?

Tags: c#

`y = Math.Tanh(x)` is the hyperbolic tangent of `x`. But I need `f(y) = x`. For the regular tangent there's Arctan, but where's Arctanh?

thanks!

Comment: here you can find it in external library: https://rtmath.net/help/html/bc0280ef-e8f3-b0c9-a2ce-4d6f6a3320e5.htm

Comment: Microsoft claims it is in Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 for [C++ AMP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh265137.aspx): [atanh Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh308337.aspx) Would that be an option for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think the C# libraries include the arc hyperbolic trig functions, but they're easy to compute:

```
atanh(x) = (log(1+x) - log(1-x))/2
```

In C#:

```
public static double ATanh(double x)
{
    return (Math.Log(1 + x) - Math.Log(1 - x))/2;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you implement one by yourself? You can find the equation e.g. [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseHyperbolicTangent.html) and tt's not that difficult:

```
public static class MyMath
{
    public static double Arctanh(double x)
    {
        if (Math.Abs(x) > 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("x");

        return 0.5 * Math.Log((1 + x) / (1 - x));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the Inverse HTangent is can be calc by doing Log((1 + X) / (1 – X)) / 2

Answer (score 0):

I installed MathNet from the package manager. It has MathNet.Numerics.Trig.InverseHyperbolicTangent(x) which works well enough.