# Machine Epsilon and Atanh, without Mathnet.Numerics

Tags: xamarin, f#, portable-class-library

I'm attempting a port of [GeographicLib](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/) into F#.  Ideally, I'd like it to be available as a PCL library, so that it can be accessed from Xamarin.  Unfortunately, the MathNet.Numerics and MathNet.Numerics.FSharp packages are not compatible with PCL.

My first stumbling block are the absence of the hyperbolic trig function `Trig.Atanh`, and of a representation of `Precision.MachineEpsilon`, from the standard numerical libraries.  I have searched online, but drawn a blank for the most efficient way to implement these.

Is there a straightforward way to find the optimal implementation of these functions?

Comment: This is actually 2 questions... The atanh question has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154596/wheres-the-inverse-of-math-tanh-in-the-math-libraries

Comment: The machine epsilon question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392869/where-do-i-find-the-machine-epsilon-in-c

Comment: You can also use MathNet.Numerics without the F# extensions from F#. MathNet.Numerics supports more PCL profiles than MathNet.Numerics.FSharp. See http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Compatibility.html for details.

Comment: Thanks Dana.  Both answers are helpful.

Comment: Christoph -- unfortunately, although the table says it should work, my compiler says otherwise.  However, so far I've only needed it for the two cases stated in the question, so I'll try again only when I absolutely need to load the whole of MathNet,Numerics.

Comment: That's bad news, seems like I need to request a new Xamarin license to verify. In the meantime I'd be interested in the exact compiler error.

Comment: I'm working just in Visual Studio at the moment.  It seems like it's a warning in the fsx script file rather than an outright error.  The warning reads "The type 'Complex' is required here and is unavailable"; however, I have defined only a real implementation of atanh, so I should be OK.

Comment: For reference, the branch that shows this warning is at https://github.com/SpiegelSoft/GeographicLib/tree/MathNetNumericsError/GeographicLib.  Let me know if it helps.